# How can I retrieve the derived class from a list of abstract classes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an application that displays several types of widgets.  I pass the view the base abstract class, GraphWidget. The goal is to loop through those, and create the appropriate display for each type of graph.

How would I go about looping through that collection and obtaining the appropriate information from the derived class so my view knows how to render each widget?

**EDIT** This is a .NET MVC5 application

Sample code:

```
public abstract class GraphWidget {
    public abstract string Display();
    public string Title {get; set;}
    public GraphWidget(string title){
        this.Title = title;
    }
}

public class BarGraph : GraphWidget{
     public override string Display(){
          return stuff...
     }
}
```

So for example, if I have a mix of bar graphs and pie graphs, their Display() function will be different.  I want to make sure, in my razor view, which is accepting an IEnumerable, that I can properly display each item.

Comment: You need to give more details. What kind of application it is. asp.net, wpf or winform ?

Comment: Can't you use the output of the `Display` method to tell how each item should be displayed?

Comment: @AwakeningByte How is that relevant to the question?  Inheritance works the same way in any C# application.

Comment: While I can use the Display function, if I end up adding functionality, or performing any logic such as "if this is a bar graph, put this after the line graph", how do I determine that solely from the IEnumerable of the base class

Comment: @BJMyers Yes, it is relevant. Ex. WPF's list binding will get the item type at run time and apply correct view template for each type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "is" operator to test if your GraphWidgets are of a certain derived class:

```
    var graphs = new List<GraphWidget>{new BarGraph("Bar"), new PieGraph("Pie")};
    foreach(var graph in graphs)
    {
       if (graph is BarGraph)
          { // it's a BarGraph 
          }
       else if (graph is PieGraph)
          { // it's a PieGraph 
          }
    }
```

If you need use them as the derived class, then you can use the "as" operator:

```
    /* Note: if graph is actually of type PieGraph, 
             then barGraph would be null */
    var barGraph = graph as BarGraph;
```

Answer (score 2):

As I understand you, you can use LINQ method [OfType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var list = new List<GraphWidget>();
var badList = list.OfType<BarGraph>().ToList();
```

Comment: This filters out any widget that isn't a BarGraph.